# ios tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I have an issue where I have a `UITableViewController` and when the view appears I do some calculations asynchronously which should result in the updating of specific rows in the table.

Inside the `viewWillAppear` function I calculate the necessary rows that need to be updated as follows:

```
- (void)reloadPaths:(NSMutableDictionary *)bookingsDict
{
    NSMutableArray* indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *dateKey in self.eventsToShow) {
        NSMutableDictionary *venues = [bookingsDict objectForKey:dateKey];
        if (venues) {
            int j = 0;
            NSArray *events = [self.eventsToShow objectForKey:dateKey];
            for (DCTEvent *event in events) {
                NSString *venueIdString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventVenueId];
                if ([venues objectForKey:venueIdString]) {
                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
                    [indexArray addObject:indexPath];
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

However I notice that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function is never called after and the cells do not get updated correctly. Any idea what the issue might be?

EDIT: I just noticed that if I scroll out of the view of the cell that is supposed to get updated then it gets updated when I scroll back into view. Is there no way to have it update while in view?

Comment: have you checked if `indexArray` contains valid data?

Comment: This is what I see in the debugger:

po indexArray
<__NSArrayM 0xd0c3a40>(
<NSIndexPath: 0xd0dffa0> {length = 2, path = 15 - 0}
)

Comment: I actually just noticed that if I scroll a little bit, then the cell gets updated. I guess that means the cells currently in view won't get updated until you scroll away from them?

Comment: no...it doesn't crash. It just doesn't update until I scroll the cell out of view.

Comment: Check my answer here to see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41551850/4546370

Answer (score 10):

How about wrap it?

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Here are some similar problems I have found.

[cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439383/cellforrowatindexpath-isnt-called-after-reloadrowsatindexpaths)

[UITableView's reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: (NSArray *) indexPaths failing to cause a reload unless you call it twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557504/uitableviews-reloadrowsatindexpaths-nsarray-indexpaths-failing-to-cause-a)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I read somewhere on stackoverflow that begin and end updates is not required. I tried reloading rows at path, did not work. But on wrapping ```reloadRowsAtIndexPaths``` with  ```self.tableView.beginUpdates()``` and ```self.tableView.endUpdates()``` **it worked**. Can someone explain why begin and end is needed ?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** : I think you are not getting indexPath check section might be constant as you are increasing while each object gets traversed:

```
- (void)reloadPaths:(NSMutableDictionary *)bookingsDict
{
    NSMutableArray* indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *dateKey in self.eventsToShow) {
        NSMutableDictionary *venues = [bookingsDict objectForKey:dateKey];
        if (venues) {
            int j = 0;
            NSArray *events = [self.eventsToShow objectForKey:dateKey];
            for (DCTEvent *event in events) {
                NSString *venueIdString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventVenueId];
                if ([venues objectForKey:venueIdString]) {
                    //changed here as section might be constant as i think it might be
                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
                    [indexArray addObject:indexPath];
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Try this :

```
//your code here
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: The issue still exists -- I have to scroll the cell out of view for it to get updated.

Comment: @AtulBhatia: Check if indexArray has got any indexpath or not?

Comment: no, the section is variable. If i change reloadRowsAtIndexPaths simply to reloadData it works fine.

Comment: I think reloadData after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths is the only way to work.

Answer (score 3):

For me pushing my reload code to the main queue solved the problem

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```